# Handling a POST request in Play Framework 2.2.x with Java?

Tags: java, post, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm getting started with Play 2.2.x, I'm trying to handle a POST requests, it's my understanding that I don't need to specify parameters in the conf/routes file but extract the queries using play's DynamicForm class, as below:

```
    import play.*;
    import play.api.data.Form;
    import play.data.DynamicForm;
    import play.mvc.*;  
    import views.html.*;

    public static Result hello() {
        DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
        String firstname = requestData.get("firstname");
        String lastname = requestData.get("lastname");
        return ok("Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname);
    }
```

However, I'm getting this error in Eclipse:

```
"The method form() is undefined for the type Form
```

And I'm getting this compiler when i execute "play run":

```
error: cannot find symbol
    DynamicForm data = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
```

What is wrong with this code? Is this class or method deprecated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You imported the wrong `Form` class. You need to import `play.data.Form` as shown in the [Javadoc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html).

The class `play.api.data.Form` is part of the *Scala* version of Play as shown in the [Scaladoc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form).

Comment: This is Play 2.x rule of thumb that classes in `play.api.*` are dedicated for Scala and the same without `api` are for Java controllers.

Comment: I didn't actually know that convention. Thanks for the tip, @biesior!

Comment: Right you are! I left Eclipse handle my imports automatically and I never would've imagined the problem could be there! Thank you, you are a life saver :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!